# List of String in Freemarker

Tags: list, freemarker

I have a list of string in java code:

```
List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
keywords.add("Apple");
keywords.add("Banana");
```

and I would like to display the keywords using Freemarker:
Apple, Banana

How to do that?

PS:
I read through the manual and found some articles suggesting using `<#list>`, but the output is:
Apple

Banana

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FreeMarker preserves your spaces (and EOL) but does not add any by itself. So, just put everything in the same line:

```
<#list myListName as item>${item}</#list>
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want a comma-separated list, you can use the following:

```
<#list seq as x>
   ${x_index + 1}. ${x}<#if x_has_next>,</#if>
</#list>
```

see: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#pageTopTitle

Comment: Sourceforge link is dead. Current link is http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Answer (score 15):

Since the version 2.3.20 of Freemarker, there is [a built-in command for comma-separated lists](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html).

For example, the template:

> <#assign colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]>
>
> ${colors?join(", ")}

.. will generate:

> red, green, blue

Answer (score 8):

Since version 2.3.23, you can also use the following code:

```
<#list users as user>
  <div>
    ${user}<#sep>, </#sep>
  </div>
</#list>
```

Taken from [the sep directive](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#autoid_96).

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker provides some features for whitespace control, see http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html